# Integral of a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Check whether the integral $\int_{-1}^2{f(x)[2x+1]}dx$ exists where 
>   $$f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> x+2, &\text{$x<0$}\\
> 1, & \text{$x=0$}\\
> xe^{x^2},& \text{$x>0$}
> \end{cases}$$
>   and $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer function. If it exists then calculate the integral.

I'm clueless about how to do the whole proof by definition stuff. Is there a way to prove that this function is integrable without any epsilon/delta and partition proofs?

Comment: To be integrable why is continuity needed

Comment: It is integrable split the integral up into different bounds and plug in the corresponding value for $f$ defined in those intervals

Comment: Yeah I have an idea how to calculate it but is my argument valid
 ( integrable cause of the continuity)?

Comment: It is not continuous

Comment: Yes, you can split the interval $[-1,2]$ into finitely many subintervals, on each of which the function is continuous, hence integrable.  There may be finitely many points where the function is discontinuous, but they don't affect the value of the integral.

Comment: Continuity is not the enough to have integrability. Here it is because you deal with compact intervals that also gives you boundedness. The argument would fail for other f(x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the fact that the discontinuities of $f(x)$ are of measure zero, the function is Riemann integrable. A proof of this exists [here](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/jeffrey/421/measurezero.pdf). This means we can validly take the integral of $f(x)$ on either side of the discontinuity and sum those:
$$\int_{-1}^{2} f(x)[2x+1]dx = \int_{-1}^{0}(x+2)[2x+1]dx + \int_{0}^{2}xe^{x^2}[2x+1]dx$$
Next, because $[2x+1]$ is the same value on for any x in the interval $[n, n+\frac{1}{2})$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and these new discontinuities are also of measure zero, we can seperate this into a larger sum with each value of $[2x+1]$ written out.
$$-1 \cdot \int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{2}} (x+2)dx + 0 \cdot \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{0} (x+2)dx + 1 \cdot \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} xe^{x^2}dx + 2 \cdot \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1} xe^{x^2}dx + 3 \cdot \int_{1}^{\frac{3}{2}} xe^{x^2}dx + 4 \cdot \int_{\frac{3}{2}}^{2} xe^{x^2}dx$$
Now we remove the term that is multiplied by $0$ and find $\int_{a}^{b} xe^{x^2}dx$ by setting $u=x^2$ and finding that $du=2xdx$.
$$-\int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{2}} (x+2)dx + \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}} e^{u}du + \int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{1} e^{u}du + \frac{3}{2}\int_{1}^{\frac{9}{4}} e^{u}du + 2\int_{\frac{9}{4}}^{4} e^{u}du$$
Finally we take the antiderivatives and evaluate.
$$-\left[\frac{x^2}{2}+2x\right]_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}[e^u]_{0}^{1/4}+[e^u]_{1/4}^{1}+\frac{3}{2}[e^u]_{1}^{9/4}+2[e^u]_{9/4}^4$$
$$=-\left(\frac{1}{8}-1-\frac{1}{2}+2\right)+\frac{e^{1/4}-1}{2}+\left(e-e^{1/4}\right)+\frac{3e^{9/4}-3e}{2}+\left(2e^4-2e^{9/4}\right)$$
$$=-\frac{9}{8}-\frac{e^{1/4}}{2}-\frac{e}{2}-\frac{e^{9/4}}{2}+2e^4$$
$$=\frac{16e^4-4e^{9/4}-4e-4e^{1/4}-9}{8} \approx 101.326$$